# Novel: Man gets abducted, injected with nanobots by an AI and protects the Earth from aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

Looking for a book that was about a guy who gets abducted by an alien space ship and then told to protect Earth from another alien threat by an AI made up of nanobots. The ship won't let him out to fight the enemy until he got himself injected with some of the nanobots because

> the Captain's survival is its top priority before fighting the enemy.

I think the main character named the enemy '*the Marcos*' but don't quote me on it. Does anyone have an idea on what I'm talking about? I know that it is part of a saga but not much else.

Comment: This is a good start but it's a bit sparse, including more details like when you read it would help us to help you. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: The Marcos or the Macros? Macro makes more sense if the AI is made of Nanos

Comment: I'm sorry, but we're not presently aware of any alien writings at all, much less science fiction books written by aliens. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Star Force](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69279-star-force) series of books by B.V. Larson. The blurb profile fits nicely and there are multiple reviews mentioning the "Marcos" as the enemies of humanity.

> *Earth arms marines with alien technology and builds its first battle
> fleet!*
>
> *Kyle Riggs is snatched by an alien spacecraft sometime after midnight.
> The ship is testing everyone it catches and murdering the weak. The
> good news is that Kyle keeps passing tests and staying alive. The bad
> news is the aliens who sent this ship are the nicest ones out
> there....*
>
> *SWARM is the story of Earth’s annexation by an alien empire. Long
> considered a primitive people on a backwater planet, humanity finds
> itself in the middle of a war, and faced with extinction*
>
> <sub><sup>[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/series/69279-star-force)</sup></sub>

and

> *The previous books in this series have been all out war. **War with the
> Macros, who are machines bent on eradicating all biotic life.** They
> have found Earth but one guy, Kyle Riggs, an “enhanced” human who has
> overcome serious run-ins with Macros now leads the Earth Marine Force
> and Fleet to track down and destroy the Macros. He does that with a
> vengeance in the previous four books.*
>
> <sub><sup>[sci-fibookreviews.com - “Battle Station (Star Force Series #5)” by B.V. Larson](http://www.sci-fibookreviews.com/authors/larson-battle-station-star-force-series-5-by-b-v-larson/)</sup></sub>

Comment: Yes! That's the one, thank you so much!

Comment: @Jake - [You're welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM)